# Flutter HTTP package with firebase not working for delete request, but working for post, patch and fetch?

Tags: firebase, flutter, rest, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to both Flutter and Firebase, so please bear with me.

I have a realtime database which stores (as of now) a list of products.
The `addProduct`, and `updateProduct` methods in my code are working fine. But for some reason, `deleteProduct` isn't. It's giving me a 404 error when I try to access the database through URL, even though the exact same URL is working for the `updateProduct` function.

Here is the code for `updateProduct`:

```
    final _productIndex =
        _items.indexWhere((element) => element.id == productId);
    if (_productIndex >= 0) {
      final url = Uri.parse(
          "https://flutter-shop-app-f1b23-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products/$productId.json");
      return http
          .patch(url,
              body: json.encode({
                "title": newProduct.title,
                "description": newProduct.description,
                "imageUrl": newProduct.imageUrl,
                "price": newProduct.price,
              }))
          .then((_) {
        _items[_productIndex] = newProduct;
        notifyListeners();
      });
    } else {
      print("ERROR");
    }

    return Future(null);
  }
```

And here is the code for `deleteProduct`:

```
Future<void> deleteProduct(String productId) {
    print(productId);
    final url = Uri.parse(
        "https://flutter-sdhop-app-f1b23-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products/$productId.json");
    print(url.toString());
    return http.delete(url).then((response) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
        throw HttpException("Could not delete!");
      }
      _items.removeWhere((element) => element.id == productId);

      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
```

And this is the (printed) error message :

```
I/flutter ( 5104): 404
I/flutter ( 5104): {
I/flutter ( 5104):   "error" : "404 Not Found"
I/flutter ( 5104): }
```

I tried opening the URL in my browser window, and got the same 404 error, which was puzzling since Flutter seems to be able to access it for updating without any issues. The firebase project was created in test mode, so I don't think authentication will be the issue here.

Please help on how to fix this.

Here are the database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "now < 1624300200000",  // 2021-6-22
    ".write": "now < 1624300200000",  // 2021-6-22
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use the REST API and not the official FIrebase SDKs for Flutter?

Comment: @TarikHuber actually the course I have bought for Flutter uses the REST API to teach backend, so I am just following that for now. Later when I am more comfortable in backend I will move on to Firebase SDK.

Comment: To be honest I would not recommend that solution for you. The REST API is made for use cases where there is no native SDK. Flutter has definitely a very good one you can use. If you continue with that approach you would have the double work because you can't reause anything you made with the REST API. And also the BEST stuff in Firebase like realtime listeners is not in the REST API. Authentication is a hustle with the REST API. It's only a Plan B solution when there is no native SDK.

Comment: If you want I can share with you some code snippets that you can start to work with the SDK.

Comment: Okay, I'll switch to SDK. Thanks for your help! I will be deleting this post in a few hours then

Comment: You don't need to delete it. Leave it if someone else also watched the same course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I would not recommend that solution for you. The REST API is made for use cases where there is no native SDK. Flutter has definitely a very good one you can use. If you continue with that approach you would have the double work because you can't reause anything you made with the REST API. And also the BEST stuff in Firebase like realtime listeners is not in the REST API. Authentication is a hustle with the REST API. It's only a Plan B solution when there is no native SDK.

In the link for deletion you have a typo:

```
https://flutter-sdhop-app-f1b23-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products/
```

It should be `shop` and not `sdhp`.

Comment: I will do this, but what is the problem in my original code :'(

Comment: If the database rules are completely open I can only imagine that the variable `productId` was not set as expected. Could you also share your rules with us?

Comment: I have updated my original question with database rules

Comment: They look fine. Is the value `productId` set? Does it print a valid ID?

Comment: Yes it does, same as the ID on Firebase.

Comment: OK. Found it. I update the answer. It was just a typo.